# Combinatorics / nCr - How do I set this up?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A Bag contains 5 red and 5 green gumballs. If you select 4 of them without looking, how many ways can you get exactly 3 red or exactly 2 green gumballs?

I am unsure of how to start his. I know it has to do with nCr since order doesn't matter but I am confused as to what the right answer is, i keep getting it wrong on my h/w. It's nCr something + nCr something I am almost positive.

Comment: By the way "nCr" is calculator-speak.  These numbers are called *binomial coefficients.*

Comment: You're selecting them without replacement, right?

Comment: Yeah, i'm pretty sure.

Comment: And Sammy I'm sorry that's the only way I knew of identifying it but now I know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints follow.

Take the first part: exactly three red gumballs.  How many ways can you choose the three red gumballs?  (You have five; choose three.)  How many ways can you choose the one green one?  (You have five; choose one.)  How many total ways can you choose three reds and one green?  (Multiply the two numbers.)

And the second part: exactly two green gumballs. You have five green gumballs; choose two.  You have five red gumballs; choose two.  How many total ways can you choose two greens and two reds?

Now, how many ways can you have *either* exactly three reds *or* exactly two greens?  (This is where you add the two answers.)